# How to use nth-of-type for non-sibling elements

Tags: html, css

I want to make a certain class, in this example "wrapper" have its background animate in when the page loads. I want them to appear staggered, so the first one animates in, then 1 second later the second, then one second later the third. The problem is, these are not and cannot be siblings. Because they are not siblings, I don't think you can use `nth-of-type` to accomplish this. Is there any other selector that I could use in my css to replace `nth-of-type` that would work? Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q2drLsee/1/

**CSS**

```
@keyframes animateBackground {
  100% { background-color: red; }
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  animation: animateBackground 1s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.1em;

  &:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }

  &:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<span class="wrapper">Some other text</span>
```

Comment: you can create a class for each span and add the delay to that https://jsfiddle.net/830h5fym/

Comment: For my purposes, I can't alter the HTML for this project. It is dynamically injected via a template that I am not able to alter, so I need a pure css way to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

I would use jQuery or JavaScript, it'll make your life much easier.

I used jQuery for this example, 
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2drLsee/4/).

```js
var delay = 1;
$(".wrapper").each(function() {
  $(this).css('animation-delay', delay + 's');
  delay++;
});
```

```css
@keyframes animateBackground {
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  animation: animateBackground 1s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<span class="wrapper">Some other text</span>
```

Comment: I'd prefer not to resort to jQuery, but it seems like I may have to.

Answer (score 2):

For a CSS only solution, the best I can think of is to target each `.wrapper` element individually. I don't see any way around this given the delay requirement and the variation in markup. You'll have to use `nth-child` and/or `nth-of-type` to target similarly structured markup. You also have to be sure of the order/placement of each `.wrapper` element. Any changes to the markup would require you to update the CSS which makes this solution very inflexible but so are the requirements. Not to mention that you'll likely be writing some crazy selectors.

The jQuery solution by **Itay Ganor** seems to be your best bet when it comes to flexibility and simplicity.

```css
@keyframes animateBackground {
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  animation: animateBackground 1s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.1em;
}

div:nth-of-type( 1 ) .wrapper {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
div:nth-of-type( 2 ) .wrapper {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

body > span.wrapper:nth-of-type( 1 ) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

/* or */
/*
body > span.wrapper:nth-child( 3 ) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
*/
```

```html
<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<span class="wrapper">Some other text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your content allows, you could add a second class specific to each wrapper:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  animation: animateBackground 1s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.1em;

  &.first {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  &.second {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }

  &.third {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper first">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<div>
  Some text <span class="wrapper second">some more text</span> and text after
</div>

<span class="wrapper third">Some other text</span>
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q2drLsee/2/)